# How can I sum up multiple int columns in the ORDER BY part of a mysql request?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

```
$first = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feeds ORDER BY (number1 + number2) DESC LIMIT 1");
```

This does not work. Both number1 and number2 are int columns.

Any advice?

Comment: Note that the MySQL extension is now **deprecated** and will be removed sometime in the future. That's because it is ancient, full of bad practices and lacks some modern features. Don't use it to write new code. Use PDO or mysqli_* instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should work :) Post your db schema as well as sample data and the wrong result you say you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM feeds ORDER BY (select (sum(column1) + sum(column2)) from feeds) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo field

```
SELECT *, (number1 + number2) as my_sum 
FROM feeds ORDER BY my_sum DESC LIMIT 1
```

> A **select_expr** can be given an alias using **AS alias_name**. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in **GROUP BY**, **ORDER BY**, or **HAVING** clauses.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html